# Router module in Angular 5 does not work, how to use it?

Tags: angular, angular5, redirect

I'm trying to use `Router` for redirection within my Angular 5 component.

In the `app.module` I have:

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductFormComponent } from './productform/productform.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './productform/product/product.component';
import { ProductService } from './productform/shared/product.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductFormComponent,
        ProductComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the component:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    templateUrl: 'product.component.html'
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use `this.router` within component function I'm getting the error in the console:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: "StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!"
```

I'm not sure I should add a provider and what provider?

I am new to angular, not fully understand how it works.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you keep routing information (where are app-routes/ routing module?)

Comment: You haven't defined any route. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `RouterModule.forRoot([])`. If you don't have any route yet keep it empty. Use it in `import` like below:

```typescript
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ]
```

Find more details from the [DOC](https://angular.io/guide/router)

---

**Note:**

Here is the sample code from their [DOC](https://angular.io/guide/router). If you have routes you could get idea from it.

```typescript
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }          from './app.component';
import { CrisisListComponent }   from './crisis-list.component';
import { HeroListComponent }     from './hero-list.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroListComponent,
    CrisisListComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add routing information as follows.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent }, // These are dummy information
  { path: 'hero/',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
 ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note : If you want to redirect to another component just call **window.location.replace('url')**

Comment: Please refer this routing documentation and get to know the concept. https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: So I can redirect only to another angular component? @Malindu

Comment: You can redirect to any route (url). This route will contain one or more angular components. What do you actually want to do. Without clear information I can't give a much informative answer

Comment: I just want to redirect to another page which is not an angular page @Malindu The router module actually started to work but I'm getting `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'thank-you%3Fio%3D395'` so it looks like it cannot find the address for some reason or the format is not correct

Comment: If you want to redirect to another component just call window.location.replace('url')

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've just used. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the router, tipically in the root of Your app. In Your import array use:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

You do not need to export RouterModule. 
Of course you need a routes array too